# jQuery hover effect not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-on

I have dynamically generated div tags which looks something like this:

```
<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_1"></div>
<div>

<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_1"></div>
<div>

<div class="widget widget_6">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_6"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_6"></div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_6"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_6"></div>
<div>
```

These div tabs will be generated based on user selection, so I can't know how many they will have on screen at once, all I will know is that they can have many of the same widgets on the screen and/or difference once on the screen at once.

I am trying to get a hover effect when hovering over any of these widgets.  I tried the follow, but nothing happens when hovering over `.widget`.

```
$(".widget_content").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        alert("enter");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        alert("leave");
    }
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements are dynamically added, use [delegated events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("body").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        alert("enter");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        alert("leave");
    }
}, ".widget_content");
```

Here instead of `body` you may use any static parent element of `.widget_content`.

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ex3M6/

Try in `$(document).ready(function() {`

Rest hope it fits your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".widget_content").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            alert("enter");
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            alert("leave");
        }
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".widget_content").hover(
function () {
alert("enter");
},
function () {
alert("leave");
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text to your div tags otherwise on top of what are you mouse hovering, and your container `div` tags should have close tags correctly as well(i.e. `</div>`).

```
<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_1">dfsdfsdf</div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_1">sdfsdf</div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_1">sdfsdf</div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_1">sdfsdfsdf</div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_1">sdfsdf</div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_1">ggggg</div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_1">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_1">ssss</div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_6">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_6">sssss</div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_6">fgggg</div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_6">fdff</div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_6">dfgdfgdfg</div>
</div>
```

your jquery code works after with this change,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div[class^='widget_content']").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            alert("enter");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            alert("leave");
        }
        });

});                

</script>
```