# How to append text based on section hovered over

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

using the following HTML which is dynamically generated:

```
<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_1"></div>
<div>

<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_1"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_1"></div>
<div>

<div class="widget widget_6">
    <div class="widget_header widget_header_6"></div>
    <div class="widget_sub_header widget_sub_header_6"></div>
    <div class="widget_content widget_content_6"></div>
    <div class="widget_footer widget_footer_6"></div>
<div>
```

I have the following script which works:

```
$("body").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        console.log( "enter" );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        console.log( "leave" );
    }
}, ".widget_content");
```

My question is, how do I replace the text in whichever `.widget_content` is hovered over, without affecting the other `.widget_content`'s?

Comment: why ask the same question again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266610/jquery-hover-effect-not-working/13266856#13266856

Comment: @Swarnajith: `why ask the same question again stackoverflow.com/questions/13266610/… – Swarnajith`.  It's a totally different question...

Comment: you should have added this question as a comment on the answer which you accepted in that link, rather than a new question

Comment: @Swarnjith: Normally, I get told off for doing that, and get told that I should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that

```
$(this).text('updated text');
```

OR

```
$(this).html('updated text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better try to learn jquery than asking each five minutes a new/same question. However, here is a snippet:

```
$("body").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).text("some new text");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        console.log( "leave" );
    }
}, ".widget_content");
```

Comment: @oshirowanen will you ask in 2 minutes how to reset text using old one on mouseleave?

Comment: I don't need to, but if you want me to because of the points, let me know.